# ArcGIS Pro interpolation point data along a line (river depth)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation, rivers, depth

I'm analyzing habitat suitability using river depth data. However, my data are pretty basic: point data of the water levels at measuring stations (so literally points, not cross sections).

First, I'm trying to interpolate these data to the river sections between the stations, but which methods should I use?

I have tried kernel interpolation with barriers and I've read about others using it for similar purposes, but I'm not entirely sure whether it makes sense or not. In the literature I've read about using linear interpolation, but I'm not sure how to do this in ArcGIS Pro.

I am very much a beginner when it comes to GIS.

Comment: Hi, could you find any solution?